# How to forward traffic between clients using socat?

Tags: sockets, networking, netcat, socat

Suppose socat listens on TCP:8888. Client A and Client B both connects to it. What command should I use to forward traffic sent by Client A to Client B, and Client B to Client A? I know `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8888 TCP4-LISTEN:8889` can forward between two ports. So I can connect Client A and Client B to 8888 and 8889 respectively to achieve this. But is there a way to use a single port?

Also I found that using `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8888 TCP4-LISTEN:8889` I must connect a client to 8888 before connecting another to 8889. How to make it accept connection at any of the two ports?

Comment: I guess that `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8888 TCP4-LISTEN:8888` doesn't work?

Comment: No. when I connect with ```nc localhost 8888```. Socat outputs "address already in use" and terminates

Comment: Try `socat TCP4-LISTEN:8888 TCP4-LISTEN:8888,reuseaddr`? If it works, I'll make it an answer

Comment: Same problem as above "address already in use"

Answer (score 0):

`socat` by default is not able to identify connected clients.
If you listen port via `socat` and `clientA` and `ClientB` connects to it, then if you send same message from socat terminal, clients will be identified randomly.
Means sometimes `clientA` and sometimes `ClientB` will recieve message. This is default behavior of `socat`.
Because socat TCP is not statefull connection for. There is no socket session identifier in `socat` , neither `nc`.

But if `clientB` in inernet and you can forward listening trafic to that.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following command does what you want (on Linux):

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8888,reuseaddr TCP4-LISTEN:8888,reuseaddr
```